# How do I clean up my Postfix master.cf file and ensure there is no backscatter?

Tags: centos, postfix

I have a master.cf file located here: http://pastebin.com/8rwN69X7

I have a feeling that I do not need both `smtp` and `smtps`. I also think I can delete the `#465` line. I don't think I need the `submission` lines either as they seem to be duplicates of stuff in `main.cf`, but I'm not sure and don't know what they do. I also wanted to make sure there is no backscatter from spam checks.

Answer (score 0):

master.cf and main.cf are totally different beasts.

master.cf is like a inetd.conf - it controls which of Postfix's daemons are running, which ports and IPs they bind to and the such.

And yes, you can delete the "#465" line, since it's commented out anyway :)

With your current master.cf, Postfix will most likely be listening on ports 25 (SMTP), 465 (SMTPS) and 587 (SUBMISSION).

Backscatter cannot be controlled using master.cf, main.cf is the only relevant config file for that.

Comment: So Spamassassin won't bounce invalid messages? This line in `master.cf`: `-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject` is very similar to this line in `main.cf`: `smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, ...`.

Comment: I can't tell, since main.cf shows how the system is configured.